# Setting kernel parameters for "Ubuntu for Raspberry Pi"

Tags: kernel, raspberrypi

I have installed [Ubuntu for Raspberry Pi 20.04 LTS 64-bit](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi) on a Raspberry Pi 4.

Now I want to add the `threadirqs` kernel parameter.

But neither the [usual Ubuntu GRUB way](https://askubuntu.com/q/19486/132098) nor the usual [Raspberry Pi OS way](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/cmdline-txt.md) of setting kernel parameters work.

As a comparison, on a bullseye-based Raspberry Pi OS, `threadirqs` can be enabled by adding `threadirqs` to `/boot/cmdline.txt`, e.g.

```
$ cat /boot/cmdline.txt
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=70118e11-02 rootfstype=ext4 fsck.repair=yes rootwait threadirqs
```

`threadirqs` features will be available after reboot.

Comment: For the Ubuntu Raspberry pi image the cmdline.txt file is in /boot/firmware.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 has reached the end of life. It is not supported here anymore.

Comment: @user68186, I have fixed my question, as it **also** pertains to a 20.04 LTS version (end of life 2030).  By the way, I find it doesn't make sense to close questions which are still valid for current and possibly future versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is located at `/boot/firmware/cmdline.txt`.